# Can Entra / Microsoft Graph API let me view invited users' calendars

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to provide calendar scheduling functionality to my SaaS app.  It is being used by a couple people who run small businesses and not corporations with existing Azure / Entra tenants.

My goal is to be able to send an email to their Office 365 outlook where they can consent to my app accessing their calendar.

Once this is achieved I want my server to poll their calendars and let changes there trigger changes in my app.

I am new to Entra and Graph api, feeling overwhelmed and unsure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to integrate your SaaS app with Microsoft 365 calendars using the Microsoft Graph API.

Inthe Azure Portal, Navigate to "Azure Active Directory" > "App registrations" > "New registration."
Fill in the required details to register your application.
Configure authentication settings,make sure that you request the necessary permissions for calendar access.

Generate a consent URL for users to grant permission to your app.
Send an email to users with the consent URL. They click on the link to provide consent.

Specify a redirect URI where users are redirected after granting consent. Handle the OAuth2 authorization code flow in your app.
Exchange the authorization code for an access token. Store this token securely.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0